# Validation Errors on Eclipse RCP Application with xtext language

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

I use an language developed with xtext in my eclipse rcp application. When I import a project containing files from this language I have

> can't resolve reference ...

errors for nearly every element in every file. When I open these files inside the editor, it seems the validation runs again. I got only black error markers(I have no idea where they come from) on the site of the file but no error underlining since no errors are available. I can now validate this file again and the black markers disapear and the marker in the project explorer does also.

This behaviour seems like an unfinished validation in the project initialization. Does anybody know about this problem or maybe has an idea where I could've messed this up?

Here are the builder and nature configured in the .project file:

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.xtextNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: are you sure you have build automatically on? does the project have xtext nature? which builders are configured on the project (.project file)

Comment: I added the entries from the .project file. And I'm not sure that I have build automatically on. Can you tell me what's this about?

Comment: build automatically you can see in the `Project`menu. in your model project a java project or not. if yes are model files in a source dir? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: The build automatically preference is turned on. The project ist no Java project. I only have confidential files atm, so sharing a screenshot is not possible, sry.

Comment: then i cant help. did you try creating a hello world mydsl and have a look if problem happens there too? did you have a look at error log?

Comment: It seems the generated bin folder is causing the problem. So as you asked in the second question, ther is a source dir. What do the different builder do? In my project, I only provide files of my own language on no java classes. Is it nescessary to run the JavaBuilder then?

Comment: please show a screenshot how this looks like